# vtune User mode Sampling no call stack information

Tags: c++, windows, intel-vtune

When I use User-Mode Sampling to try to analyze the hotspots in my Windows virtual machine with Intel VTune, I am unable to obtain the callstack information. Instead, it shows the message:

> No data to show. The collected data is not sufficient.

[image]

`I have configured the symbol path as follows:`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WumFX.png)

When I run the `vtune-self-checker.bat`, it provides the following output:
[image]

How can I retrieve the callstack information when using User-Mode Sampling?

Comment: Please, post your error messages as text, not as an image. [This is why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: The following analyses have failed on the system:
* Hotspots with HW event-based sampling, HPC Performance Characterization, etc.
* Microarchitecture Exploration
* Memory Access
* Hotspots with HW event-based sampling and call stacks
* Threading with HW event-based sampling
* GPU Compute/Media Hotspots (characterization mode)
* GPU Compute/Media Hotspots (source analysis mode)

Comment: that's the message when I run the vtune-self-checker.bat. And I can't input all the message because of characters limit

Comment: And the Vtune GUI show the info:"Top Hotspots 
This section lists the most active functions in your application. Optimizing these hotspot functions typically results in improving overall application performance.
No data to show. The collected data is not sufficient."

Comment: You can edit your question, and add the error message there. Though, perhaps you won't be able to edit your message at the moment, seeing how there's already an edit waiting for approval.